# wp_handle_upload() from the backend

Tags: wordpress

I've used `wp_handle_upload` from the front end and it works fine.
Now I want to receive base64 string (jpg) from API POST store in metabox then turn it in to jpg(until here it works fine). Then I need to upload it in the media library and attach it to a post.
when I pass the file with `file_get_contents` or `fopen` it does not work. Any ideas?

```
function base64ToImage($base64){

    $img = base64_decode($base64);
    require_once( ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/image.php' );
    require_once( ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/file.php' );
    require_once( ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/media.php' );

    // wp_handle_upload( $_POST['img'], 0 );
    $fp = fopen(get_template_directory()."/xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.jpg", "w+");
 
    // write the data in image file
    fwrite($fp, base64_decode($base64));
 
    // close an open file pointer
    fclose($fp);

     wp_handle_upload( file_get_contents("../" ."/xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.jpg"), 0 );



    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

So to my past self and to anyone that might find this useful.
I used the `wp_upload_bits` function instead, subsequently I used
`-wp_insert_attachment`
`-wp_generate_attachment_metadata`
`-wp_update_attachment_metadata`
`-set_post_thumbnail` in order to associate the image with a specific parent post.